# Where can I buy Cure Poison potions?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I need some Cure Poison potions.  I know I can't make my own, so does anyone know of shops that sell it and where?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [UESP wiki](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Potions#Other_Leveled_Potions):

> **Cure Poison**
>
> - Cannot normally be traded with apothecary merchants.
> - 95% chance of 1-11 bottles being sold by apothecary merchants, but only if you have unlocked the Merchant
> - 25% chance of being carried by Elgrim, Nura Snow-Shod and Mjoll the Lioness
> - 3% chance of being carried by Silver Hand members

Comment: You can also find a Necklace of Poison Immunity.